# How to make a PFQueryTableView work inside a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get the benefits of the PFQueryTableViewController to work inside of a a regular UIViewController that has a TableView embedded in it. Because apparently I can't load data from parse onto my TableView. It just pops up as a blank tableView with none of my information from Parse in it unless the code is ran on a UITableViewController, then it has no problems. But I'm trying to get my program to run on a Table View thats in a UIViewController. And whenever I change the @Interface from- @interface MainWall: UIViewController to @interface MainWall :PFQueryTableViewController, the app crashes.

So my question is, is there anyway around this? I read a little about subclass, subviews and Container View Controller but no one actually showed how to create them besides Parse's AnyWall code, which was extremely confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that you will have to use a container view controller. [Here is a good link with a container view tutorial](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/)

Comment: your implying this is the only way, you should revise to clarify and include some references from the tutorial to eliminate potential issues with [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

Comment: Finally got around to this and Yes it worked! So Thank You Very Much for the Link!

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeking Parse's table view controller they provide, use [this](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html): `PFQueryTableViewController` (not just a "PFQueryTableView", which I believe does not exist in the framework)

Otherwise, you must handle the data fetching and everything yourself, which does not diverge much from what you would normally do in a `PFQueryTableViewController` except that you have to get your data in viewDidLoad and store the array of PFObjects.

However you could also use containers and put a `PFQueryTableViewController` inside another view controller, but never the less **I find that handling Parse data fetching, etc. in my own view controller is better for the versatility I can achieve.**

Comment: This is the better answer, just because parse has PFQTVC doesn't mean it's good. It's just easier to set up for those not yet well versed with obj-c or swift. It's a good starting point, but as you grow and learn you'll see that this causes more problems and less flexibility than using your own UITableView and simply just querying into that. You can perform all tasks that PFQTVC does in your own, you just don't subclass it.