# How to make devcards work inside Cursive?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojurescript, figwheel, cursive

I am able to run figwheel in Cursive using the instructions on the [lein-figwheel site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080605/how-to-make-a-pfquerytableview-work-inside-a-uiviewcontroller) (only the option opening files in Intellij didn't work). I would like to do the same for [devcards](https://github.com/bhauman/devcards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up running figwheel inside Cursive (including for devcards). Cursive failed to always update the running code (I followed the instructions at the lein-figwheel site). For running devcards using `lein`, the instructions at the [devcards site](https://github.com/bhauman/devcards) work fine. Be careful as minor mistakes, in the `project.clj` file, will make devcard fail (I suggest you run their example and then adapt it to your project).